# CDK8s Deploy results in a "Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0"

Tags: cdk8s

Any idea about this issue?

node -v
v12.19.0

npm --version
8.13.2

```
cdk8s import --language python
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk8s-cli/node_modules/cdk8s/lib/api-object.js:28
        this.name = props.metadata?.name ?? this.chart.generateObjectName(this);
                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk8s-cli/node_modules/cdk8s/lib/index.js:13:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
```